# Are there any online public chess databases I can upload my own games to?

Tags: database, online

Does there exist any online public chess database that I can upload my own games to (so that others can look at them)?  I know that sites where you can play online will store games (that you played on that site) so they can be viewed, but I'm trying to find somewhere to store my OTB games that were not played online.

I was thinking that chess-db.com might be a possibility, it seems at first glance like that's what it's supposed to be for - but I note that it is aware of me (it knows my USCF ID and everything), but it has my rating wrong (what they have is years out of date) and it also has a list of games supposedly played by me that I never played.  So I am not sure if that site is actually legitimate.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest going to lichess.org and creating one or more studies for this. You can choose to make these public or private or only visible to those you give the link to. Within a study, you can upload the PGN of your games as separate chapters. You will need an account to make studies, but creating an account and using any of the study features is entirely free.

For each game, you can fill in as much or as little information about the players/situation as you want. Lichess studies also have advanced commentary features, so that you can describe your thoughts as well as annotate which moves you thought were interesting, blunders, etc. Personally, I find it useful to add variations I've found that I feel are worth further consideration - whether I found the variation during or after the game.

As an example, [here is one study I made to contain the most interesting Tabletop Simulator games I've played](https://lichess.org/study/rRxO5EpF), as well as my annotations of the games.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is share your games with others via the internet then the easiest way is to create your own database of your games and upload the file to your cloud storage area, be it Dropbox, Google Drive or Microsoft One Drive. Then you can share read-only links to the file. This is the only free method of doing this that I know.

If you are prepared to pay then you can do something similar with a Chessbase account but you can only share with other Chessbase users. There is an article on the Chessbase site explaining how this works [here](https://en.chessbase.com/post/tutorial-sharing-databases).

Answer (score 1):

When you play in a tournament (especially a FIDE rated one) and submit a carbon copy of your notation, that's how the game can end up in some database (such as chess-db). Chess players wouldn't be allowed to upload whatever they want to well known database sites since then they could deliberately mislead people who look them up to prepare for them.

You can of course upload your games via your own methods (such as on your own site), but this won't be very popular on a Google search.

Comment: None of the tournaments I play in have asked me to submit a copy of my scoresheet (even though I do use scoresheets that make a carbonless copy - sometimes I give it to my opponent).  The games that are listed in my name on chess-db aren't games I ever played, they're all outside the US (and I've never played outside the US).  chess-db actually does let people upload arbitrary games, and it seems like it would be really useful - if I could get rid of the games I never played...  I have e-mailed them to ask for their help.  No response so far.  I'm still not sure it's actually legitimate.

Comment: @patbarron Wait, there are games under your name on chessdb that aren't yours? Is there another chess player with your name? Try searching them up on the FIDE website's player lookup.

Comment: Yes, there are games that are not mine.  It's certainly possible there are other players with my name (USCF has one other player with the same name except for middle initial), but there's no one in the current FIDE rating list with my name.  However, chess-db has associated these mystery games with my name *and* my USCF ID number.

Comment: @patbarron Hmmm ok that seems like an error then. It's good you emailed them.